# Using Git on Windows, how do I ensure normalized line endings in repository and no conversion in work dir?

Tags: git

Using Git on Windows, I want to ensure normalized line endings in the repository and no conversion in working directory?

We are now using .gitattributes files with `* text=auto` to ensure the Git repositories are normalized. When a .gitattributes file is used, all the text files in the repository are stored as LF. That is fine. The problem is when they are written out to the working directory, it is changing the line endings to core.eol even though we don't have `core.autocrlf=true`. When .gitattributes is used, it should have the same behavior as not using .gitattributes when writting out to the working directory. It should change the line endings only when `core.autocrlf=true`. I'll file a bug. Marked in red is behavior I believe should be changed.

[image]

In my use case, I'm building on build servers, both TeamCity and Visual Studio Online, and can not set `core.autocrlf=input`. I'll use the open source F# compiler as an example. The project uses `* text=auto` and does not specify `*.fs text eol=lf` in its [.gitattributes](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/.gitattributes). If you download [il.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/absil/il.fs) from the GitHub repository, the line endings are LF. When they are checked out by the build server, they are CRLF. This means that the checksums don't match and source indexing using [SourceLink](https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink) doesn't work.

As a workaround, I've recommended that we set `*.fs text eol=lf` in the .gitattributes file. Not everyone is happy with this.

Also, can someone with 1500 reputation points tag this as "sourcelink".

Comment: Didn't you just answer it yourself? Use `core.autocrlf=input`, since `text=auto` should only be used if `core.autocrlf` is not specified (according to https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Comment: At first, I was hoping for different behavior, then I looked for a `* text=input`, but didn't find one. The use case is that I don't have the ability to set `core.autocrlf=input` on the build servers. I'll add more details about the use case to the question.

Comment: I filed feature request [mysysgit/mysysgit#164](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/164) to **add `text=input` option for gitattributes**.

Answer (score 0):

Update your global settings via the command prompt

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: In my use case, I'm wanting to build on the build servers where I can't set the global settings. Git's default behavior should be that the working directory files match the repository. This was the behavior until recently. I blogged about this and more in a post titled "Time to Kill the Carriage Return". http://blog.ctaggart.com/2014/02/time-to-kill-carriage-return.html